# Safari IOS clip-path does not work

Tags: ios, css, svg, safari, clip-path

Im creating an web application in Angular 5 that should work fine also on mobile devices. The progress bar of it is an svg image, created in Adobe Illustrator and exported to svg. I have made it work fine on Android, Mac and Windows (all browsers) but Im having a problem with clip-path being rendered on Chrome or Safari browser that runs on IPhone IOS.

I have tried managing it by normal

```
clip-path: url(#clip-path);
```

and also by webkit specific:

```
-webkit-clip-path: url(#clip-path);
```

But insted of something like that:

Image preview:

[image]

I get this on Safari or Chrome on IOS:

Wrong image preview:

[image]

So it looks like clipping is completely ignored, but weird thing is that on Mac it works fine.

Please suggest how to solve it, as Im struggling with it for few days.

I have also created demo on

## [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-syjn1y)

Comment: Try to connect the mobile to the computer and inspect what happens

Comment: What specific version of iOS are you testing on? Have you checked https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path for possible incompatibility?